# How to iterate through a treenode collection by comparing each node within another list

Tags: c#, algorithm, winforms

I have a treeview which contains several nodes (over 100.000) with checkboxes, which represent folders/files.

Besides that I have a string list which contains maybe 10-20 elements.

I want to iterate through the all tree and check for each node if the fullpath of the node is contained in that string list, if yes than I set the checkbox for that node.

My problem is with the performance. If the string list contains more than 2-3 elements, it takes ages for the program to show the result.

Here is my code:

```
void SetCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection allNodes, IEnumerable<string> excludedFiles)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in allNodes)
    {
        foreach (string ef in excludedFiles)
        {
            if (ef == node.FullPath)
            {
                node.Checked = true;
            }
        }

        if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            SetCheckedNodes(node.Nodes, excludedFiles);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea to improve the performance of this code?

Comment: `several nodes` and `(over 100.000)` is quite a description.

Comment: Accessing properties can be a killer, I would make variables out of these for faster access but also profile the code with Alt-F2. And if your items are immutable you could make a string to hash function and you'd compare integers instead of strings which is much faster.

Comment: @Aybe: Please write your comment as an answer and I will accept it. I am precalculating the hashes for the excludedFiles and for the nodes on the fly and with  the integer comparison the code runs instant. So the problem was the string comparison.

Comment: I may be missing some information, but is there a reason you aren't traversing the tree from the root node? If you just follow a path through the tree your look up times will be SIGNIFICANTLY faster.

Comment: @A.B. I've added an answer I tried from scratch, that might give you a few ideas.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed ... it's a good and well written question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will check about 1000 items on 100000 almost instantly:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // assuming tree view has a root node already

            treeView1.CheckBoxes = true;
            treeView1.BeginUpdate();

            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            // read first 100000 paths from a file
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\files.txt").Take(100000).ToArray();
            builder.AppendLine($"Time taken reading paths: {watch.Elapsed}");

            // populate tree view with these paths
            watch.Restart();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var root = treeView1.TopNode;
                var keys = line.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    var nodes = root.Nodes;
                    root = nodes.ContainsKey(key) ? nodes[key] : nodes.Add(key, key);
                }
            }

            builder.AppendLine($"Time taken populating tree: {watch.Elapsed}");

            // add some garbage and shuffle
            watch.Restart();
            var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ToArray();
            var random = new Random();
            var strings = range.Select(s => lines[random.Next(lines.Length)]);
            var garbage = range.Select(s => s.ToString());
            var array = strings.Concat(garbage).OrderBy(s => random.Next());
            builder.AppendLine($"Time taken randomizing: {watch.Elapsed}");

            // now check checkable items
            watch.Restart();
            foreach (var line in array)
            {
                var root = treeView1.TopNode;
                var keys = line.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

                foreach (var key in keys)
                {
                    var nodes = root.Nodes;

                    root = nodes.ContainsKey(key) ? nodes[key] : null;

                    if (root == null)
                        break;
                }

                if (root == null)
                    continue;

                root.Checked = true;
            }

            builder.AppendLine($"Time taken checking items: {watch.Elapsed}");

            treeView1.EndUpdate();

            MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Differences with release build are really negligible:

[image]

So it's a different approach (written from scratch) that might give you an idea or two.

Answer (score 1):

You do a linear search in a collection, that's slow by default. 
Replace `IEnumerable<string>` with `IHashset<string>`,

and the inner `foreach` with `excludedFiles.Contains(node.FullPath)`

and this will boost it.

Also the `"continue;"` is kind of strange; it's doing absolutly nothing. A `"break;"` would have made more sense. You can stop searching after you found it, there is no reason to continue. But with a hashset you don't need that anyway.

Comment: You are right about the "continue" (I removed it). Other than that, please read my comment what I wrote for "Aybe". The problem was the string comparison.

Comment: I was writing my answer after having read your comment "is was the string-comparison". No, its not. The string comparison is just a part of the problem, it's the number of comparisons you do (did). Changing from string to Hash/int gives you linear improvement, 10 times faster, Using a dictionary/Hash search algorithm, gives exponential improvement, power of 10 faster, cause you decrease the number of compares dramatically.
And you don't have to do much programming, just use `new Hashset(excludedFiles)`  and everything is fine, you don't need a search loop any more.

Comment: Check my answer, I did suggest that at first instance but it turns out to not be really necessary in most cases, speed is good enough with a better algorithm for the majority of cases.

Comment: That's what I say. A better algorithm. Your idea is good.  I just disliked A.B.'s analysis "it's the string-comparison". You did more than just replacing string-comparison by int-comparison.
To find an item in a big list, is a job for a dictionary or a Hashset. That's a very simple basic idea. "Good enough" doesn't mean impossible to improve.
So is your `Cotainskey(key) ? this[key]` for example  searching twice in the Collection, with  IndexOfKey you would search only once.
Further improvements show only on larger collections.
I guess replacing the "continue" with "break" gave a boost.